# How to register multiple key presses at the same time in pygame

Tags: pygame, keyboard

Every time I try to operate player one and two or try to use the pickup key it stops the players. here is my code:

```python
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700,700))
screen.fill((255,255,255))
pygame.key.set_repeat(5,5)
import random
p1="james_u"
p2="billy_u"
p1_face= "r"
p2_face= "r"
p1h="health p1 4 HP"
p2h="health p2 4 HP"
player = 1
BG=pygame.image.load("Bgg.png")
H1=4
H2=4
G1X=random.randint(10,500)
G1Y=random.randint(10,500)

x_collide=[]
y_collide=[]

class Dude:
    char_width = 0
    char_height = 0

    def __init__(self, newX, newY):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.img = pygame.image.load(p2+".png")
        myRec = self.img.get_rect()
        Dude.char_width = myRec[2]
        Dude.char_height = myRec[3]
        
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))

    
    def moveLeft(self):
        self.x = self.x - 5   
        p2_face = "l"

    def moveRight(self):
        self.x = self.x + 5
        p2_face = "r"    
       
    def moveUp(self):
        self.y = self.y -5
        p2_face = "u"    
    
    def moveDown(self):
        self.y = self.y +5
        p2_face = "d"        
        
    def getRec(self):
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3])    

class Broski:
    char_height= 0
    char_width= 0
    def __init__(self, newX, newY):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.x_spd = 0
        self.y_spd = 0
        self.img = pygame.image.load(p1+".png")
        myRec = self.img.get_rect()
        Broski.char_width = myRec[2]
        Broski.char_height = myRec[3]
        
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))
    
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_spd
        self.y += self.y_spd
        self.x_spd = 0
        self.y_spd = 0
        
        
    def getRec(self):
        print(myRec)
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3]) 


class BG:
    def __init__(self, newX, newY):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.img = pygame.image.load("Bgg.png")
    
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))

    def getRec(self):
        myRec = self.img.get_rect()
        print(myRec)
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3])

class Health:
    def __init__(self, newX, newY, newH):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.img = pygame.image.load(newH +".png")  
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))

class Weapon:
    gun_list=[]
    gun_list_A=[]
    gun_count=0
    Player = "None"
    def __init__(self, newX, newY, idle_Image, Speed, Damage, Arc_Angle, R_Speed, active_Image):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.active_Image = active_Image
        self.idle_Image = idle_Image
        self.img = pygame.image.load(idle_Image +".png")  
        myRec = self.img.get_rect()
        Weapon.gun_count+=1
        Weapon.gun_list.append(Weapon.gun_count)
        Weapon.gun_list.append(newX)
        Weapon.gun_list.append(newY)
        Weapon.gun_list.append(myRec[2])
        Weapon.gun_list.append(myRec[3])
        Weapon.gun_list.append(Speed)
        Weapon.gun_list.append(Damage)
        Weapon.gun_list.append(Arc_Angle)
        Weapon.gun_list.append(R_Speed)
        Weapon.gun_list_A.append(Weapon.gun_list)
        Weapon.gun_list=[]
    def playerlock(self, player):#once picked up it locks onto the player
        if math.sqrt((player.x-self.x)**2 + (player.y-self.y)**2) <= 150:
            self.img=pygame.image.load(self.active_Image+".png")
            Weapon.Player = player
        #positianal argument for weapons placement on player

    def draw(self, window):
        if Weapon.Player == bro:
            self.active_Image = self.idle_Image + p1_face
            self.x = bro.x -10
            self.y = bro.y -10
        if Weapon.Player == person:
            self.active_Image = self.idle_Image + p2_face
            self.x = person.x - 10
            self.y = person.y - 10
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))
        #idle image must be gun name and nothing else while active is directional
    def getRec(self):
        print(myRec)
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3])

class Bullet:
    bul_width=0
    bul_height=0
    x=0
    y=0
    def __init__(self, newX, newY, Image, Player):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        x=self.x
        y=self.y
        self.player = Player
        self.img = pygame.image.load(Image +".png")
        myRec = self.img.get_rect()
        Bullet.bul_width= myRec[2]
        Bullet.bulsd_height= myRec[3]
    def shoot():
        print("shoot")
    
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))

    def getRec(self):
        print(myRec)
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3])



class Object:
    ob_count = 0
    ob_list=[]
    ob_list_alpha=[]
    def __init__(self, newX, newY, Image):
        self.x = newX
        self.y = newY
        self.img = pygame.image.load(Image)
        myRec = self.img.get_rect()
        Object.ob_count += 1
        Object.ob_list.append(Object.ob_count)
        Object.ob_list.append(newX)
        Object.ob_list.append(newY)
        Object.ob_list.append(myRec[2])
        Object.ob_list.append(myRec[3])
        Object.ob_list_alpha.append(Object.ob_list)
        Object.ob_list = []
   
    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.img, (self.x,self.y))

    def getRec(self):
        print(myRec)
        return (self.x, self.y, myRec[2], myRec[3])

# class does_collide:
#     def __init__ (self, item):
#         self.it = item
#         x_collide.append((self.it.img.get_rect(1))+Object.ob_list_alpha[1])
       
crate_1=Object(200,200,"Yellow_Cargo_Closed.png")
crate_2=Object(500,200,"Red_Cargo_Closed_Horz.png")
col_l = False
col_r = False
col_u = False
col_d = False
col_l2 = False
col_r2 = False
col_u2 = False
col_d2 = False
bggt=BG(0,0)
bro=Broski(10,10)
none=Broski(50,10)
person=Dude(665,560)
p1health=Health(35,620,p1h)
p2health=Health(465,620,p2h)
Gun_1=Weapon(G1X,G1Y,"glock",10,2,60,3,"glocku")
B_P1_1=Bullet(20,20, "Bullet_P1_1", "P1")
PL = none
while(True):
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    bggt.draw(screen)
    person.draw(screen)
    bro.draw(screen) 
    B_P1_1.draw(screen)
    crate_1.draw(screen)
    crate_2.draw(screen)
    p1health.draw(screen)
    p2health.draw(screen)
    Gun_1.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type==QUIT):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #DEBUG HELP
            if key[pygame.K_LCTRL] and [pygame.K_b]:
                print("deebug")
                print(Gun_1.idle_Image+p1_face)
            for i in range (Object.ob_count):
                if  (person.x + Dude.char_width) >= Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and person.x <= (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]) and (person.y + Dude.char_height) >= Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and person.y <= (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]):
                    if person.x < Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and (person.y + Dude.char_height) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and person.y < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]):
                        col_r = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_r = False
                    if (person.x + person.char_width) > (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]) and (person.y + Dude.char_height) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and person.y < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]):
                        col_l = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_l = False
                    if person.y < Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and (person.x + Dude.char_width) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and person.x < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]):
                        col_d = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_d = False
                    if (person.y + person.char_height) > (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]) and (person.x + Dude.char_width) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and person.x < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]):
                        col_u = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_u = False
                else:
                    col_l = False
                    col_r = False
                    col_u = False
                    col_d = False
            for i in range (Object.ob_count):
                if  (bro.x + Broski.char_width) >= Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and bro.x <= (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]) and (bro.y + Broski.char_height) >= Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and bro.y <= (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]):
                    if bro.x < Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and (bro.y + Broski.char_height) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and bro.y < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]):
                        col_r2 = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_r2 = False
                    if (bro.x + bro.char_width) > (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]) and (bro.y + bro.char_height) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and bro.y < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]):
                        col_l2 = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_l2 = False
                    if bro.y < Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] and (bro.x + bro.char_width) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and bro.x < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]):
                        col_d2 = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_d2 = False
                    if (bro.y + bro.char_height) > (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][2] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][4]) and (bro.x + bro.char_width) > Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] and bro.x < (Object.ob_list_alpha[i][1] + Object.ob_list_alpha[i][3]):
                        col_u2 = True
                        break
                    else:
                        col_u2 = False
                else:
                    col_l2 = False
                    col_r2 = False
                    col_u2 = False
                    col_d2 = False

            if key[pygame.K_UP] and col_u == False or (key[pygame.K_UP] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_o]):
                if person.y > 10:
                    person.moveUp()
                    p2="billy_u"
                    p2_face="u"
                    if key[pygame.K_o]:
                        PL = person

            if key[pygame.K_w]  and col_u2 == False or (key[pygame.K_w] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_q]):
                if bro.y > 10:
                    bro.y_spd += -5
                    p1_face="u"
                    p1="james_u"
                    if key[pygame.K_q]:
                        PL = bro

            if key[pygame.K_DOWN] and col_d == False or (key[pygame.K_DOWN] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_o]):
                if person.y < 560:
                    person.moveDown()
                    p2="billy_d"
                    p2_face="d"
                    if key[pygame.K_o]:
                        PL = person
                    

            if key[pygame.K_s] and col_d2 == False or (key[pygame.K_s] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_q]):
                if bro.y < 560:
                    bro.y_spd += 5
                    p1="james_d"
                    p1_face="d"
                    if key[pygame.K_q]:
                        PL = bro

            if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and col_l == False or (key[pygame.K_LEFT] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_o]):
                if person.x > 10:
                    person.moveLeft()
                    p2="billy_l"
                    p2_face="l"
                    if key[pygame.K_o]:
                        PL = person
                    

            if key[pygame.K_a] and col_l2 == False or (key[pygame.K_a] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_q]):
                if bro.x > 10:
                    bro.x_spd += -5
                    p1="james_l"
                    p1_face="l"
                    if key[pygame.K_q]:
                        PL = bro

            if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and col_r == False or (key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_o]):
                if person.x < 665:
                    person.moveRight()
                    p2="billy_r"
                    p2_face="r"
                    if key[pygame.K_o]:
                        PL = person

            if key[pygame.K_d] and col_r2 == False or (key[pygame.K_d] and col_d == False and key[pygame.K_q]):
                if bro.x < 665:
                    bro.x_spd +=5
                    p1="james_r"
                    p1_face="r"
                    if key[pygame.K_q]:
                        PL = bro

                
            if B_P1_1.x == person.x and B_P1_1.y == person.y:
                if H2 > 0:
                    H2 -= 1
                B_P1_1.x = bro.x +10
                B_P1_1.y = bro.y +10

#             p1h ="health p1 "+str(H1)+" HP"
#             p2h ="health p2 "+str(H2)+" HP"
            if H1 == 3:
                p1h="health p1 3 HP"
            if H1 == 2:
                p1h="health p1 2 HP"
            if H1 == 1:
                p1h="health p1 1 HP"
            if H1 == 0:
                p1h="health p1 0 HP"
            if H2 == 3:
                p2h="health p2 3 HP"
            if H2<3 and H1>1:
                p2h="health p2 2 HP"
            if H2<2 and H2>0:
                p2h="health p2 1 HP"
            if H2<1 and H2>-1:
                p2h="health p2 0 HP"
                
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if key[pygame.K_UP]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_w]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_s]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_a]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    print("hurr")
                if key[pygame.K_d]:
                    print("hurr")
            Gun_1.playerlock(PL)
            bro.move()
            p2health.img=pygame.image.load(p2h+".png")
            p1health.img=pygame.image.load(p1h+".png")
            bro.img=pygame.image.load(p1+".png")
            person.img=pygame.image.load(p2+".png")
            Gun_1.img=pygame.image.load(Gun_1.active_Image + ".png")
#             Gun_1.draw(screen)
```

I thought it was stopping because it was using a class function, but I did some messing around and figured it was the keys and I couldnt find anything online.

I've thought about switching the if statements to detect when the key isn't pressed but if pygame only lets one key be pressed at a time then the same issue arises.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get it to detect multiple keys at once please let me know.

Comment: I am not familiar with pygame, but should `key=pygame.key.get_pressed()` be outside the `for event in pygame.event.get()` loop? Wouldn't that mean only one keypress could be evaluated in the entire loop?

Answer (score 1):

I refer to the answer by wyattis in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37126399/13682048. The built-in `pygame.key.get_pressed()` returns a list and one can check multiple keys with

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    move_fullcube = left
```